# Bootstrap 5's input group: How to make entire input group clickable for datepicker item?

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-5

I am using the [Vue-datetime](https://github.com/mariomka/vue-datetime#readme) package for a datepicker in the UI and also am using  [Bootstrap 5's input group form componen](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/input-group/)t for placing buttons on sides of input fields.

**I would like to make the entire input field clickable, as well as the button. Does anyone have any advice on how to do so? My current attempt just makes only a small part of the input field clickable. How to extend it for the entire field, as well as the button?**

Screenshot of my current attempt:
[image]

I have a codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-glade-orwv9?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Note: It would be nice to hide the inner date field border, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue by using some Bootstrap utility classes.

Applying `form-control and p-0` to the wrapper will give it the look of a normal bootstrap input.

Then we can add some classes to the input itself using the `input-class` prop.
Here we'll add `w-100` to stretch it to full width. `py-1 and px-2` to give the placeholder some padding and then `border-0` to remove the base border on the `<input />`.

```js
class="form-control p-0" 
input-class="w-100 py-1 px-2 border-0"
```

You'll also want to move the hidden input field to after the datetime component, to avoid the border-radius being messed up on the left side.

The button we can make into a `<label>` and point to the input to allow us to open the datepicker by pressing it. We can style the label using the `btn` classes.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/vue-datetime@1.0.0-beta.14/dist/vue-datetime.min.css" />

<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/luxon@1.28.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/weekstart@1.1.0/dist/commonjs/main.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue-datetime@1.0.0-beta.14/dist/vue-datetime.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="p-4">
  <label class="form-label" for="date_input">Date:</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <datetime input-id="date_input" type="date" ref="dateInput" class="form-control p-0" input-class="w-100 py-1 px-2 border-0" placeholder="Choose a date..." aria-label="Choose a date..." aria-describedby="dateField" auto required></datetime>
    <input type="text" class="d-none" placeholder="Choose a date..." aria-label="Choose a date..." aria-describedby="dateField" />
    <label for="date_input" class="btn btn-primary">
      Button
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```